# Hide excel gridlines using EPPLUS

Tags: .net, vb.net, epplus

What is the method/command for hiding excel spreadsheet gridlines in EPPLUS?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
WorkSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false
```

Hope this does the trick!